# REST Api print queue design

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a REST Api for a testing software and I have a doubt. I searched a lot but it's not clear enough for me. My scenario is a queue which contains multiple jobs to be printed. These jobs are complex objects and the printing workflow is another complex action. I don't know which operation fit best to this. According to this, it should be a POST?

http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html

In this case my action will fit better into an RPC model but we need to use REST according to that 95% of actions fits perfectly to this model.

In case that is a POST I must send the queue that I want to print inside the body?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to expose through your REST API but I would think about this.

You could expose a resource with path `/printjobs` that corresponds to the print queue. Using a method `POST` would add a job in the queue. The returned status code would be `202 Accepted` since it's something asynchronous and return an identifier for the new job.

Something in background would be responsible to handle job in the queue. I think that it's something different from the REST API.

Then you could use a resource `/printjobs/{id}` that will give you hints about the status of the job (method `GET`), suppress it (method `DELETE`) and update its status (for example to suspend it with method `PUT` or `PATCH`)/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpfull for my solution. I misunderstood some concepts about Rest but now is much clearer.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that ;-) You're welcome! This link could give you some additional hints: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/03/16/designing-a-web-api/...